# Combining 2 LINQ into one call

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm using 2 similar LINQ queries to return a result, the only difference is the where clause (`&& s.OptIn == "Yes"`). Is there a way to execute this with only one query?

Instead of having a result of

```
A   2 
B   3
```

and another result of

```
A 1
B 1
```

I want to have

```
A   2   1 
B   3   1
```

Here's the LINQ:

```
        var result = from s in pdc.ScanLogs
                     from e in pdc.Exhibits
                     from ce in pdc.ClientEvents
                     where s.ExhibitID == e.ExhibitID
                     && e.ClientEventID == ce.ClientEventID
                     group 1 by new { ce.EventID } into d
                     select new {
                         EventID = d.Key.EventID,
                         Count = d.Count()
                     };

        var result = from s in pdc.ScanLogs
                     from e in pdc.Exhibits
                     from ce in pdc.ClientEvents
                     where s.ExhibitID == e.ExhibitID
                     && e.ClientEventID == ce.ClientEventID
                     && s.OptIn == "Yes"
                     group 1 by new { ce.EventID } into d
                     select new {
                         EventID = d.Key.EventID,
                         Count = d.Count()
                     };
```

Comment: is your goal to have only a single SQL call to the database?  Or to have one result object for your results?

Comment: well with the given code there will be no sql call ;p - but good question hence the +1

Comment: I'm interested in one SQL and and one result object. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can supply a predicate in the Count method. An example is below:

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var counts = new { CountAll = list.Count(), CountEven = list.Count(i => i % 2 == 0) };
Console.WriteLine(counts.CountEven);
```

A similar query written for Linq-To-Entities also worked and produced working SQL.

I haven't fully reconstructed your sample, but you should be able to rework it to something like this.

```
var result = from s in pdc.ScanLogs
                from e in pdc.Exhibits
                from ce in pdc.ClientEvents
                where s.ExhibitID == e.ExhibitID
                && e.ClientEventID == ce.ClientEventID
                group new { s, e, ce } by new { ce.EventID } into d
                select new
                {
                    EventID = d.Key.EventID,
                    Count = d.Count(),
                    CountOptIn = d.Count(item => item.s.OptIn == "Yes")
                };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IQueryable<ScanLog> scanlogs = pdc.ScanLogs;
if (filter) scanlogs = scanlogs.Where(...);
var result = from s in scanlogs
   ...
```